# onClick wait 1 second then run code

Tags: android, onclick, locationmanager

I have this code that by clicking on button the camera centers in my location on map.

The problem is: When I click the first time, the camera goes too far away from my position and I suspect that the onClick method is making the location manager get only partial coordinates ( When I click the same button for the second time it gets the right spot.)

So, here is the code:

What I would like to try was:

1. I click on the button

2.

```
   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
   location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
   latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

This code runs

3. wait 1 second

4.

```
   CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng);
   CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
   map.moveCamera(center);
   map.animateCamera(zoom);
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(latlng));
```

This code runs.

Is this possible?

Sorry the basic question but I'm new to Java/Android programming (3 weeks or so and I still find some basic things like this hard to achieve).

PS: The code is running almost in perfection, the only thing that it's bothering me is that I have to click twice for it to get in the spot that it's supposed to be ( in the first click it gets about 3 to 4 km away from it - estimate calculation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to do so is by using handlers. Try below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng);
   CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
   map.moveCamera(center);
   map.animateCamera(zoom);
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(latlng));
    }
},1000); //adding one sec delay
```

Try going over this for more information on handlers.

[www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Writing the code this way is a bad idea.  Very frequently getLastKnownLocation will return null.  Instead what you should do is use requestSingleUpdate to get a single location update with fresh data, and put any code dependent on that location into the onLocationChanged function.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an working code using requestSingleUpdate that fetches my location? 

I'm asking this because I've spent a bit of time search for this and every code crashes ( but I'm new to this programming thing )